# Rubymine reveal current document in project tree / project drawer

Tags: rubymine

If i'm working on a file in RubyMine, is there a shortcut key or context menu option where I can "reveal in sidebar" and it basically would expand the project tree down to the file I currently am working on?

This is a feature in both TextMate and Sublime Text 2, but I haven't found it RubyMine yet.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`Navigate` | `Select In`, **Project View**. Shortcut would depend on keymap, default is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: Ok Great. Its actually Navigate | Select in and yes the `alt` + `f1` also brought up that menu option.

Thanks CrazyCoder

Comment: Any idea how to turn on this behavior by default?

Comment: @idrinkpabst I just added an answer for that

Answer (score 42):

Also you can use target icon in Project view. With Rubymine 2019, it'a new target icon.

[image: Rubymine 2019]

Comment: Alternatively, you can click on the gear icon and check "Autoscroll from source". This will auto scroll to the file which is opened in editor.

Answer (score 17):

You can use a setting that automatically does that.

In **Project View** go to settings and activate **Autoscroll From Source**

It will open current file in the project tree like sublime or atom does.

Comment: In 2023, this is now called "Always Select Opened File".

Answer (score 11):

In RubyMine 2019.3:

1. click on the project gear icon
2. select "Always select opened file"

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marco. This was the default setting I was looking for. Works in RubyMine 2021.1.1 as well.

Answer (score 2):

To change the keymap go to

```
File -> Settings  (RubyMine -> Preferences)
Keymap -> 
Main Menu -> Navigate -> Select In
```